# WooCommerce log MaxMind geolocation

Tags: woocommerce, geolocation, maxmind

I am starting a WooCommerce shop which contains only digital products.
During checkout customers have to enter their name and email, and not their country.
However I would like to log their country with the MaxMind geolocation integration.

I have entered my MaxMind License Key in the WooCommerce settings, and the "*Default customer location*" is on "*Geolocate*".
Should this enable me to find a customers location with "*wc_get_order*"?
Because when I do a var_dump on this array it does not seem to contain anything relating to the location as found by MaxMind. Or is the customer location perhaps not logged?

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: For info: In WooCommerce if customer has not set any country, the country fields will be set to the geolocated country. So what you can do is to keep country field(s) hidden with CSS. This way the country will be always the geolocated country.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I think I was wrong, because hiding the field with CSS during checkout does also hide the geolocated country in both the confirmation email and the WooCommerce backoffice.
But thanks to your comment I have found that the geolocated country is logged on the same location in the 'wc_get_order array', whereas before I was expecting to see a field relating to MaxMind.